# PHP - compile requests across multiple HTTP requests from same visitor (keep-alive) and execute when certain threshold is reached?

Tags: php

Is it possible to compile several http requests from the same user (using keep-alive) and execute a given script, when a certain threshold?

The thing is that I'm doing a series of queries from Excel which due to QueryTable limitations can max take a url of 2048 characters. Hence I'm forced to split the URL up as I have some very long queries. Furthermore, the requests are made from my own webserver that pulls data from a 3rd party API.

For instance:

- It's estimated that the query needs 3 separate queries/requests to
  stay below the 2048 characters.
- 3 separate http requests are passed from Excel to my own webserver with the query string divided into 3 to stay below the 2048 character threshold.
- As it is now, each http request from excel tells the webserver to send a request to the 3rd party API, parse the data and send it back to Excel.
- Instead of doing so, I would like that my own webserver compiled these requests before passing them on, to avoid unnecessary overhead. And first when all requests are compiled and parsed it should be sent back to Excel.

Is this even possible? And if so, is it possible to ensure that separate users won't have their response mixed with other users' requests?

Comment: Did you consider POSTing the info using AJAX? Then you could do everyting in one communication

Comment: Well actually I didnt, but it's obiously a good idea

Comment: @RiggsFolly just a consideration: utilizing the `POST` method in querytables (`.posttext`) wouldn't that have the same restrictions/limitations as `GET`? I mean, using a querytable i'm guessing it would simply be parsed as a query string, the same way as a `GET ` request does, hence the same character limit?